# htaccess - using subdomains and admin dir

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have `.htaccess` like this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)?$ admin/index.php?a=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?(([^.]+).)?domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?s=%3&d=domain.com&a=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

I need access to directory /admin where is index.php and use subdomains also.
Access to admin is ok, when i remove: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?(([^.]+).)?domain.com [NC]`

The dir look like: `index.php; admin/index.php`

Can somebody help me, what i do bad?

Any information helps, thank you.

Comment: Need more details. What URL are you trying and what error are you getting.

Comment: I want access to domain.com/admin in admin area. And something.domain.com as normal page which give me back subdomain value and domain value. I get 404 and the second part of rule is used for admin url also.

Comment: Still unclear to me what 2nd rule is doing.

Comment: Ok, Sir i will explain. Example: 2nd rule do from name.domain.com/find this domain.com/index.php?s=name&d=domain.com&a=find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip `/admin` from 2nd rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin/index.php?a=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(([^.]+)\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?s=%3&d=domain.com&a=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This cannot solve me problem. I try test it various times. I use htaccess.madewithlove.be for debug info and result was: `1   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d This variable is not supported: %{REQUEST_FILENAME}
2   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f This variable is not supported: %{REQUEST_FILENAME}
3   RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)?$ admin/index.php?a=$1 [QSA,NC,L] This rule was not met because one of the conditions was not met
4    `

Comment: `5   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f This variable is not supported: %{REQUEST_FILENAME}
6   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/ [NC] This condition was not met
7   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?(([^.]+).)?domain.com [NC] This condition was not met
8   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?s=%3&d=domain.com&a=$1 [QSA,NC,L] This rule was not met because one of the conditions was not met`

Comment: Result URL is now: http://domain.com/admin/?s=&d=domain.com&a=admin Error code: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: No, only in base (root) directory Sir.

Comment: I change the: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/ [NC]` to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]` and it works. Thank you for assistance you help me a lot!

Comment: I can check your previous answer as correct without "/". Please send it one more time, becouse somebody need maybe the second answer.